# I am trying to close html boostrap modal from component.ts file

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-bootstrap

I have been trying to close a bootstrap modal from a component.ts file after successful submission of the form.

I tried to follow the instructions here:

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/api which has a stackblitz 
https://stackblitz.com/run?file=index.html

While the stackblitz has got the open function defined :

```
open(content) {
    this.modalService.open(content, {ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title'}).result.then((result) => {
      this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
    }, (reason) => {
      this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
    });
  }
```

While all i want to do is, as shown in the html file

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="modal.close('Save click')">Save</button>
```

More precisely just this:

```
(click)="modal.close('Save click')"
```

However, I already have a click-function on the button, which means the same function should be able to call the function to close the modal on successful form submission.

I think the part that I am stuck with is this: "A reference to an active (currently opened) modal. Instances of this class can be injected into components passed as modal content."

Comment: I was able to close the Modal and back drops using jquery though that was not what i wanted to work, but the solution works, here are few steps that I did 

In the my.component.ts added these files, 
import * as $ from 'jquery'
then called this $('.modal-backdrop').remove(); What i was looking to do was to close it using this.modalService.dismissAll()

Comment: Your stackblitz link is broken. I would rather you get a correct answer then continue to use jQuery to close the dialog. I would prefer you learned to use Angular without jQuery at all.

Comment: I agree @cgTag which is exactly why i asked this question, I wanted to get this done using the API, jquery was last resort. Also stackblitz by the way was from https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples whoever said developer's life is easy just copy+paste :-)

Comment: This is how i achieved this: "injected into components passed as modal content" 
Step1 => import {NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap'; 
Step 2 =>in the constructor  private modalService: NgbModal.
But that does not seem to work as 
=> this.modalService.dismissAll() 
does not seem to give the desired result

Comment: I haven't used ngBootstrap in a long while, but I'll try answering.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject the `NgbActiveModal` object into the component used as the popup dialog, and then call the close method on that reference.

```
@Component({..})
export class MyDialogComponent {
    public constructor(private _modal: NgbActiveModal) { }

    public close() {
        this._modal.close("result");
    }
}
```

See this doc reference:

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/api#NgbActiveModal

Comment: You can also use `NgbActiveModal` if you don't have the actual modal ref.

Comment: @Mike I think you're right. I'll update the answer. thanks.

Comment: I am getting an error  NullInjectorError: No provider for NgbActiveModal! I have imported import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap'; in app.module

Comment: @Mike when i import NgbActiveModal in the component controller file i get an error

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use `NgbActiveModal` class. Feel free to check out the API [here](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/api#NgbActiveModal).

On your component.ts, you will need to import the `NgbActiveModal` class.

```
import { NgbActiveModal, NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
.
.

constructor(activeModal: NgbActiveModal) {}

close() {
  this.activeModal.close();
  // or this.activeModal.dismiss() depending on your requirements
}
```

And on your component.html, you may bind the `close()` method with your click event on your close button.

```
<button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="close()">
  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
```

The NgBootstrap site has a decent demo using the `NgbActiveModal`. I have forked a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q46jr8?file=app/modal-component.ts) for you reference.

Comment: I am getting an error:  NullInjectorError: No provider for NgbActiveModal! I have import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap'; in app module

Comment: May I know which version of ng-bootstrap are you using? The some of the versions require you to use NgbModule.forRoot(), on the imports

Comment: I am using the following:  "ng-bootstrap": "^1.6.3", "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.1.1". plus i have used   NgbModule.forRoot() in app module. Are we supposed to ng-bootstrap and @ng-bootstrap in package.json?

Comment: Oh, you only need `@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap` on your package.json. I am not sure whats wrong, but did you try following the way the importing/declarations are done on the demo? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q46jr8?file=app%2Fmodal-component.module.ts

Comment: This line that's missing in my app.module is => import { NgbdModalComponent, NgbdModalContent } from './modal-component'; and NgbdModalComponent and NgbdModalContent i think i can ignore that and replace it with my code, right? Or am i doing that wrong!

Comment: Yup! In the example, `NgbdModalComponent` represents the 'parent' component (aka the rest of the logic for that page), wheres `NgbdModalContent ` represents the 'child' component (aka the component that contains purely the logic for the modal). So, you should replace those names with your respective components' names

Comment: I reran npm install after removing all the files, but i still get this error, i guess this is the cause of the problem in the first place. Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[MyformComponent -> NgbActiveModal]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[MyformComponent -> NgbActiveModal]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for NgbActiveModal!